# Allowing users to change order of list of items

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to allow users to create a list of items with their categories in the order they want. For some reason categories are appearing in the order users are choosing. But, items are showing in a random order! even though I am using the same code for them!

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])


class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)])
```

**views.py**

```
def items_list(request):
    category = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("order")
    item = Item.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("order")
    return render(request, 'fav.html', {"items": item, "categories": category})
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to confirm you've identified the right issue, have you explicitly checked the `order` field of the models to ensure they've been set properly?

Just above `return` in your view: `print item.values_list('order', flat=True)`

Comment: Where should I add "print item.values_list('order', flat=true)

Comment: Above the `return` in your view code. This is just a quick way of printing the ordering values out into the console to ensure that they are what you think they are.

Comment: I am getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
 def items_list(request):
    category = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by("order")
    items = [Item.objects.filter(category=c).order_by('order') for c in category]
    return render(request, 'fav.html', {"items": items})
```

After this,u should edit ur template.loop items twice, the first time items will be split by category, the second time items in one category will be split by id and ordered by order.